# Need Suggestions for real-time number or object detection with Arduino + MATLAB?

Tags: arduino, matlab, first-robotics

I'm working on a line follower robot. its a kind of waiter robot. and i am facing  problems in detecting customer table. can you guys please suggest me some ideas to detect customer table. i want to include some image processing methods to achieve this goal. can you guys suggest me some article or tutorial with code to understand this?.  or if have any other reliable and easy suggestion for me then that would be appreciated :)

Comment: Its not possible to do image processing using only arduino.. you need atleast single board computer.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Muhammad Faran, but I'm afraid that *Unbounded Design Questions* are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do some basic obstacle detection with an arduino your best bet is either using an ultrasonic sensor or a LIDAR. Image processing is likely to be too complex for an arduino that is also managing the rest of the robots functions. https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/arduino-obstacle-avoding-robot This robot uses an ultrasonic sensor to detect objects in front of it, so something similar to this except it stops when it senses a table may be suitable for your needs

Comment: One could possibly use the arduino fpga though for such a task...https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/MKRVidor4000